# Change picture in webpage using PHP every secon

Tags: php, jquery, html, image

I have webpage that dynamically changes picture source and displays new image using compination of PHP and JQuery.

This is the PHP5 script:

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "1";

    include_once "cookie_checker.php";

    function get_file_extension($filename) {
        return substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1);
    }

    $path = "./motion";
    $latest_ctime = 0;
    $latest_filename = '';
    $exts = array('jpg');

    $d = dir($path);
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
        $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
        $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($entry));
        if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime && $extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
            $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
            $latest_filename = $entry;
        }
    }

    echo '<img src="/motion/' . $latest_filename . '" />';
?>
```

This is the Javascript part of the code:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
            $('#load_div').load('camera_stream_worker.php');}
    , 1000);
```

HTML where the image is displayed:

```
<div id="load_div">
</div>
```

The script as it is works in Firefox, but not in the Internet explorer.

Can you advise me how to display pictures in Internet Explorer also???

I do not understand why it does not work. By definition PHP is the server side programming language, and Internet explorer is working client side.

I would like to know why this works in Firefox, but not in the Internet explorer.

Thanks

Comment: Some things missing here... Where do you load the image?

Comment: Hello @Amarnasan, I have added an HTML part of the code where the image is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a problem with browser caching. To avoid your image getting cached you could send some "random" parameter with your ajax call, like a timestamp:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
  $('#load_tweets').load('camera_stream_worker.php?time=' + Date.now());}
, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all change your php content type as your are returning html content. it will work

Comment: Hello @Vigikaran, I have changed the Content-Type to text/html, but it is stilll not working.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try once